# Display external functions outputs

Tags: c, clips

I try to display external function results in CLIPS.

External functions are written in C language, as follows (in kruskal.c file):

```
#include "clips.h"
#include <math.h>

#define V 6 
#define INT_MAX 9999
int kruskal(void *environment,
    DATA_OBJECT_PTR returnValuePtr);
int find(int i);
void union1(int i, int j);

int parent[V]={0};

int find(int i)
{
    while (parent[i] != i) 
        i = parent[i];
        
    return i;
}

void union1(int i, int j)
{
    int a = find(i);
    int b = find(j);
    parent[a] = b;
}

int kruskal(void *environment,
    DATA_OBJECT_PTR returnValuePtr)
{
    
int cost[][V] = {
        { INT_MAX, 3, INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 6, 5 },
        { 3, INT_MAX, 1, INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 4 },
        { INT_MAX, 1, INT_MAX, 6, INT_MAX, 4 },
        { INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 6, INT_MAX, 8, 5 },
        { 6, INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 8, INT_MAX, 2 },
        { 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, INT_MAX },
    };
    
    int mincost = 0; // Cost of min MST.

    // Initialize sets of disjoint sets.

    for (int i=0; i< V; i++)
       parent[i] = i;
        
    // Include minimum weight edges one by one

    int edge_count = 0;

    while (edge_count < V-1)
    {
        int min = INT_MAX, a = -1, b = -1;

        for (int i=0; i<V; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<V; j++)
                {
                    if (find(i) != find(j) && cost[i][j] < min)
                    {
                        min = cost[i][j];
                        a = i;
                        b = j;
                    }
                }
        }

        union1(a, b);
        printf("Edge %d:(%d, %d) cost:%d \n",edge_count++, a, b, min);
        mincost += min;
    }

    printf("\n Minimum cost= %d \n", mincost);

}
```

The steps required to implement desired function were followed, namely,
declaration of the function in userfunctions.c, as shown below:

```
void EnvUserFunctions(
  void *environment)
  {
extern int kruskal(void *);

EnvDefineFunction2(environment, "kruskal", 'i', PTIEF kruskal, "kruskal", "00i");

//#endif
}
```

Desired output in CLIPS should be:

```
 Edge 1: (2,3) cost: 1
 Edge 2: (5,6) cost: 2
 Edge 3: (1,2) cost: 3
 Edge 4: (2,6) cost: 4
 Edge 5: (4,6) cost: 5
 Minimum cost = 15
```

The question is: How to display such outputs results in CLIPS from external function kruskal.c ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the EnvPrintRouter function to direct the output through the CLIPS I/O router system (described in section 7 of the Advanced Programming Guide). This will appropriately display the output using either the console version of CLIPS or the IDE.

```
int kruskal(void *environment,
    DATA_OBJECT_PTR returnValuePtr)
{
char buffer[256];    
int cost[][V] = {
        { INT_MAX, 3, INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 6, 5 },
        { 3, INT_MAX, 1, INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 4 },
        { INT_MAX, 1, INT_MAX, 6, INT_MAX, 4 },
        { INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 6, INT_MAX, 8, 5 },
        { 6, INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 8, INT_MAX, 2 },
        { 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, INT_MAX },
    };
    
    int mincost = 0; // Cost of min MST.

    // Initialize sets of disjoint sets.

    for (int i=0; i< V; i++)
       parent[i] = i;
        
    // Include minimum weight edges one by one

    int edge_count = 0;

    while (edge_count < V-1)
    {
        int min = INT_MAX, a = -1, b = -1;

        for (int i=0; i<V; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<V; j++)
                {
                    if (find(i) != find(j) && cost[i][j] < min)
                    {
                        min = cost[i][j];
                        a = i;
                        b = j;
                    }
                }
        }

        union1(a, b);
        sprintf(buffer,"Edge %d:(%d, %d) cost:%d \n",edge_count++, a, b, min);
        EnvPrintRouter(environment,STDOUT,buffer);
        mincost += min;
    }

    sprintf(buffer,"\n Minimum cost= %d \n", mincost);
    EnvPrintRouter(environment,STDOUT,buffer);

}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Riley, it's perfect. Mr. Riley, you are a benefactor of humanity !